# Graphing API for Android Apps?

Tags: java, android

I am starting an Android Application that will collect data and I would like to chart this data.

Where are some places I could look for a good charting API for Java to use on Android?

Comment: Try some of these, maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android?rq=1

Comment: "Where are some places I could look".  Err, Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this charting library for android

http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/

some examples

http://aspnetgeek.wordpress.com/2011/09/09/graphs-on-android-using-achartengine/
https://github.com/CodeAndMagic/AChartEngineTest

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-drawing-pie-chart-using-achartengine/

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend AChartEngine ..

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this one: http://androidplot.com/wiki/Home

This library support these charts:

```
Line charts
Scatter charts
Bar charts
Step charts
```